# How can I reduce this grep repetition?

Tags: regex, grep

Is there a way to write the following command more concisely?

```
grep -E '[A-Z](([a-z]{2})|([a-z]{3})|([a-z]{4}))' file.txt
```

Comment: Try it like `[A-Z]([a-z]{2,4})` and a single capturing group

Comment: or `[A-Z][a-z]{2,4}`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an alternation `|` for every quantifier `{2}`, `{3}`, `{4}` in a separate capturing group you could use a single quantifier `{2,4}` and a single capturing group.

```
grep -E '[A-Z]([a-z]{2,4})' file.txt
```

About the pattern

- `[A-Z]` Match single char A-Z
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[a-z]{2,4}` match 2-4 times a-z
- `)` Close group